# Powershell indexing for creating user logon name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to make a user creation script for my company to make things more automated.

I want the script to take the `Firstname + Lastname[0]` to make the users logon name, but i can't get the syntax right,
I have tried writing {} and () but no luck there.
that's the original peace from my script

```
New-ADuser...........-UserPrincipalName $fname+$lname[0]
```

any tips?

Comment: You provide barely enough information for us to help you. You might carefully re-read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: things to look into - [1] create the UPN separately & use a $Var to get things into the parameter value.///// [2] `Get-Help about_Splatting`

Comment: Seriously. Use splatting for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gabriel Luci's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55092399/45375) provides an effective solution and helpful pointers, but it's worth digging deeper:

Your problem is that **you're trying to pass *expression* `$fname+$lname[0]` as an *argument*, which requires enclosing `(...)`**:

```
New-ADuser ... -UserPrincipalName ($fname+$lname[0])
```

PowerShell has two distinct [parsing modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing), and when a *command* (such as `New-ADUser`) is called, PowerShell operates in ***argument* mode**, as opposed to *expression* mode.

**Enclosing an argument in `(...)` forces a new parsing context**, which in the case of `$fname+$lname[0]` causes it to be parsed in *expression* mode, which performs the desired string concatenation.

**In *argument* mode, *unquoted* arguments are *implicitly* treated as if they were enclosed in `"..."`, i.e., as *expandable strings* under the following circumstances**:

- If they don't start with `(`, `@`, `$(` or `@(`.
- If they either do *not* start with a variable reference (e.g., `$var`) or do start with one, but are followed by other characters that are considered part of the same argument (e.g., `$var+$otherVar`).

Therefore, `$fname+$lname[0]` is evaluated as if `"$fname+$lname[0]"` had been passed:

- The `+` become part of the resulting string.
- Additionally, given that inside `"..."` you can only use variable references by themselves (e.g., `$fname`), not *expressions* (e.g., `$lname[0]`), `$lname[0]` won't work as intended either, because the `[0]` part is simply treated as a *literal*.

Embedding an *expression* (or a *command* or even *multiple* expressions or commands) in `"..."` requires enclosing it in `$(...)`, the subexpression operator, as in Gabriel's answer.

For an overview of **PowerShell's string expansion rules**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).

---

The following examples use the `Write-Output` cmdlet to illustrate the different behaviors:

```
$fname = 'Jane'
$lname = 'Doe', 'Smith'

# WRONG: Same as: "$fname+$lname[0]", which 
#         * retains the "+" 
#         * expands array $lname to a space-separated list
#         * treats "[0]" as a literal
PS> Write-Output -InputObject $fname+$lname[0]
Jane+Doe Smith[0]

# OK: Use an expression via (...)
PS> Write-Output -InputObject ($fname+$lname[0])
JaneDoe

# OK: Use an (implicit or explicit) expandable string.
PS> Write-Output -InputObject $fname$($lname[0]) # or: "$fname$($lname[0])"
JaneDoe


# OK: Use an intermediate variable:
PS> $userName = $fname + $lname[0]; Write-Output -InputObject $userName
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a string for the `UserPrincipalName`, with the variables in the string:

```
New-ADuser -UserPrincipalName "$fname$($lname[0])"
```

PowerShell can usually figure out when you put a variable inside a string. When it can't, like in the case of `$lname[0]`, you enclose it in `$()`.

This is called "variable expansion" (other languages, like C#, call it "string interpolation"). Here's a good article that describes it in more detail: https://powershellexplained.com/2017-01-13-powershell-variable-substitution-in-strings/

Answer (score 0):

i just saw the answers and a minute before i realized that i should actually set it up as another variable, `$logon = $fname+lname[0]`
and pass it as `-userPrincipalName $logon`.

Thanks for the help, you guy are the best!